# Java 8 Stream Filter - Sort based pdate

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

Am trying to sort the filed in filter.

Input Document / Sample Record:

```
DocumentList: [
    Document{
        {
            _id=5975ff00a213745b5e1a8ed9,
            u_id=,
            mailboxcontent_id=5975ff00a213745b5e1a8ed8,                
            idmapping=Document{
                {ptype=PDF, cid=00988, normalizedcid=00988, systeminstanceid=, sourceschemaname=, pid=0244810006}
            },
            batchid=null,
            pdate=Tue Jul 11 17:52:25 IST 2017, locale=en_US
        }
    },
    Document{
        {
            _id=597608aba213742554f537a6,
            u_id=,
            mailboxcontent_id=597608aba213742554f537a3, 
            idmapping=Document{
                {platformtype=PDF, cid=00999, normalizedcid=00999, systeminstanceid=, sourceschemaname=, pid=0244810006}
            },
            batchid=null,
            pdate=Fri Jul 28 01:26:22 IST 2017,
            locale=en_US
        }
    }
]
```

Here, I need to sort based on pdate.

```
List<Document> outList = documentList.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getInteger(CommonConstants.VISIBILITY) == 1)
    .parallel()
    .sequential()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
    .sort()
    .skip(skipValue)
    .limit(limtValue);
```

Not sure how to sort

```
"order by pdate DESC"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This will not compile: `List` does not have `sort()` method - it has `sort(Comparator<T>)`, and that method does not return anything.

Comment: Also, combination `.parallel().sequential()` is an exact equivalent to `.sequential()` alone. That chain looks like you thrown some random operations at it, to see if anything sticks.

Comment: This seems like the return value of some NoSql database to me... Tell the database to sort, skip and limit, it doesn't make any sense to load the whole dataset in memory to then skip and limit the final result...

Comment: if you found an answer helpful, please `accept` it

Answer (score 11):

You can use `.sorted()` Stream API method:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Document::getPDate).reversed())
```

And the full, refactored example:

```
List<Document> outList = documentList.stream()
  .filter(p -> p.getInteger(CommonConstants.VISIBILITY) == 1)
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Document::getPDate).reversed())
  .skip(skipValue).limit(limtValue)
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
```

---

Few things to remember about:

- If you do not care about the `List` implementation, use
  `Collectors.toList()`
- The `collect()` is a terminal operation and should be called as the last operation
- `.parallel().sequential()` this is totally useless - if you
  want to parallelize, stick to `.parallel()` if not, do not write
  anything, streams are sequential by default
- The whole Stream will be loaded to the memory for the sake of sorting

Comment: I just deleted my last comment when i saw your edit ^^.

Comment: Don't sorted streams materialize their whole datasets into memory (at least I think they do) regardless of whether `limit` is in place? If so, it warrants a mention, I think.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov they does indeed, but the returned list will contains only `limit` elements. I don't think is was use for optimization purpose here.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond, well, in case that `DocumentList` is huge and streamed over IO from disk, he may get a surprise at later point.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov He may, let's hope he won't :)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov good idea - I added info about that just in case - but I assume that OP realizes that sorting can be performed only on the fully loaded data set

Comment: @pivovarit, I made example implementation that might enable `sort and limit` even for huge datasets, based on collector that skips elements. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach to [pivovarit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45421591/7470253), which might be useful in case your dataset is potentially too big to hold in memory at once (sorted `Stream`s have to maintain whole underlying dataset in intermediate container to provide ability to sort it properly).

We will not utilize stream sort operation here: instead, we will use data structure that will hold as many elements in set as we told it to, and will push out extra elements based on sort criteria (I do not claim to provide best implementation here, just the idea of it).

To achieve this, we need custom collector:

```
class SortedPileCollector<E> implements Collector<E, SortedSet<E>, List<E>> {
  int maxSize;
  Comparator<E> comptr;

  public SortedPileCollector(int maxSize, Comparator<E> comparator) {
    if (maxSize < 1) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Max size cannot be " + maxSize);
    }
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    comptr = Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);
  }

  public Supplier<SortedSet<E>> supplier() {
    return () -> new TreeSet<>(comptr);
  }

  public BiConsumer<SortedSet<E>, E> accumulator() {
    return this::accumulate; // see below
  }

  public BinaryOperator<SortedSet<E>> combiner() {
    return this::combine;
  }

  public Function<SortedSet<E>, List<E>> finisher() {
    return set -> new ArrayList<>(set);
  }

  public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
    return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
  }

  // The interesting part
  public void accumulate(SortedSet<E> set, E el) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(el);
    Objects.requireNonNull(set);
    if (set.size() < maxSize) {
      set.add(el);
    }
    else {
      if (set.contains(el)) {
        return; // we already have this element
      }
      E tailEl = set.last();
      Comparator<E> c = set.comparator();
      if (c.compare(tailEl, el) <= 0) {
        // If we did not have capacity, received element would've gone to the end of our set.
        // However, since we are at capacity, we will skip the element
        return;
      }
      else {
        // We received element that we should preserve.
        // Remove set tail and add our new element.
        set.remove(tailEl);
        set.add(el);
      }
    }
  }

  public SortedSet<E> combine(SortedSet<E> first, SortedSet<E> second) {
    SortedSet<E> result = new TreeSet<>(first);
    second.forEach(el -> accumulate(result, el)); // inefficient, but hopefully you see the general idea.
    return result;
  }
}
```

The above collector acts as mutable structure that manages sorted set of data. Note, that "duplicate" elements are ignored by this implementation - you will need to change implementation if you want to allow duplicates.

Use of this comparator for your case, assuming you want three top elements:

```
Comparator<Document> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Document::getPDate).reversed(); // see pivovarit's answer
List<Document> = documentList.stream()
  .filter(p -> p.getInteger(VISIBILITY) == 1)
  .collect(new SortedPileCollector<>(3, comparator));
```

Comment: Considering that `contains` and `remove` have the same complexity as `add`, all bearing a lookup operation, it might be better to use just `if(set.add(el)) set.pollLast();`, which *might* create a node that will be removed right afterwards, but bears only a single lookup operation and is much simpler than `E tailEl = set.last(); Comparator<E> c = set.comparator(); if (c.compare(tailEl, el) <= 0) { return; } else { set.remove(tailEl); set.add(el); }`…

Comment: @Holger, what you suggest is entirely valid, assuming that we are OK replacing `SortedSet` with `NavigableSet` (in my example implementation we can, since `TreeSet` is-a `NavigableSet` anyway).  I understand that my implementation might not be among the better approaches, and I even said that I only intend to give basic idea.

Comment: If you follow [the usual pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html), you provide a factory method return a `Collector<E,?,List<E>>`, making the actual intermediate container type an implementation detail. Using methods like [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) in the factory method, you don’t even need to implement `Collector`.

Comment: @Holger, `Collector.of` would require function factories for accumulator and combiner, that capture `maxSize` parameter, and pass it to extracted static methods with arity of 3 (current implementation works around by having captured a reference to `this`). While this approach is generally more preferred because it allows testing things separately, I feel this would be slightly too much code for such simple answer. Good points on design though.

Comment: Well, the accumulator could be simplified to a single lambda expression, `(set,el) -> { if(set.add(el) && set.size()>maxSize) set.pollLast(); }`, likewise the combiner `(set1,set2) -> { if(set1.addAll(set2)) { while(set1.size()>maxSize) set1.pollLast(); } return set1; }`, indeed, they are capturing `maxSize`.

Answer (score 0):

After you got the resulted list, do this assuming `Document.getPDate()` returns the `pDate`

`Collections.sort(outList, Comparator.comparing(Document::getPDate).reversed());`

Comment: is a simple comparator is going to be in `DESC` order?

Comment: By default, it is in ascending order

Comment: As i though, the OP asked for DESC order

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond the OP didn't state that. My bad, see it

Comment: @Dummy, see at the bottom, he wanted `order by pdate DESC`.

Comment: @Dummy read the question again (at the very end) `order by pdate DESC`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, fixed it.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond Fixed it

Comment: Thank you all!

`&& (!StringUtils.isEmpty(req.getPType()) ? (((Document)d.get("idmapping")).getString("ptype").equalsIgnoreCase(req.getPType())) : true))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Document::getPdate).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Compile Error Getting
**The type Document does not define getPublicationdate(T) that is applicable here**, in "comparing(Document::getPdate"

Comment: After adding sorted am getting below error.
**The type Document does not define getPdate(T) that is applicable here**

Comment: What is the method name in `Document` class that returns the `pdate` ?