# How to limit in groupBy java stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

This is my course model in class named `Course`:

```
public class Course{
    private int courseId;
    private String courseName;
    private Teacher teacher;
}
```

This is my teacher model in class named `Teacher`:

```
public class Teacher{
    private int teacherId;
    private String name;
}
```

I want to get a `Map<String, List<Course>>` but if the `teacherId` is repeated just add that `Course` into list of map.

I am using `groupBy` for it

```
Map<Integer, List<Course>>  result = courses.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.getTeacher().getTeacherId(), Collectors.toList()));
```

and it's giving result as expected.

But I want to `limit` here that As soon as 5 teachers are found stop to process and returned the result.

How can it be done??

Comment: What now? Five or ten teachers? And what do you mean with “stop to process”? Are you comfortable with incomplete `Course` lists?

Comment: This would be significant work - are you certain you can't just let all of them in and only access the first `10`?

Comment: Yes, stop the process as soon as 10 Teachers are found. Whether the course list is processed completely or not.

Comment: probably a custom collector, where all elements that come after the condition is met are simply a NOOP

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon but this could be possible that first 5 have repeated Teacher's id. So, in that case there will not be 5 unique results.

Comment: I think there's a confusion in your question. Assume you have 100 courses in your list. then how you can be sure that all the courses for first five teacher are added to the map? What you are asking would stop as soon as the first course is added to the map for that fifth teacher. Don't you need all the courses for all first five teachers?

Comment: @Eugene can you please add it as an answer so that I can check.

Comment: @STaefi `Don't you need all the courses for all first five teachers? ` **NO**, just first five teachers with the courses processed till now.

Comment: @ltiGupta: Why bothering yourself using collectors and grouping by? Use a simple while loop to iterate over the list and add teachers to a `Set` and your while loop should stop after the size of `Set` reaches to 5 or 10 or ...

Comment: @Staefi, it really depends on what is the dataset. If we're assuming that the whole thing is in memory, then loop might work. Otherwise, it will do much more work that is required (but then I'd argue that this requirement be met at the level which has this dataset, such as an SQL statement).

Comment: @ItiGupta, you might want to check [one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45422605/7470253) and adapt it for your case.

Comment: what if we use a external map and then in the stream put a filter to check the map size(i mean the keyset size) and proceed further only if keyset size is < 10 then write a consumer to write to map. not sure if that is what you want

Comment: @M.Prokhorov regardless of what the source of the stream is, you can always use a loop, as you can get an `Iterator` from the stream

Comment: @Holger, I can, but the stream itself is not an `Iterable`, certain kinds of loop will not work with it directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There’s no direct support for this, as stopping and living with potentially incomplete data is rather unusual.

A straight-forward solution collecting the first five groups completely, would be

```
Set<Integer> firstFive = courses.stream()
    .map(c -> c.getTeacher().getTeacherId())
    .distinct().limit(5)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
Map<Integer, List<Course>> result = courses.stream()
    .filter(c -> firstFive.contains(c.getTeacher().getTeacherId()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.getTeacher().getTeacherId()));
```

Here, the `Course` lists of these first five teacher ids are complete.

---

A solution that truly stops after encountering the 5th teacher id, would be simpler with a loop:

```
Map<Integer, List<Course>> result = new HashMap<>();
for(Course c: courses) {
    result.computeIfAbsent(c.getTeacher().getTeacherId(), x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(c);
    if(result.size() == 5) break;
}
```

But there is not much sense in collecting lists of `Course`s, when you can’t trust these lists afterwards. Keep in mind, that even the source list’s very last element could belong to the first encountered teacher ID, so you need to process the entire list even if you are interested in only one teacher’s complete list of courses.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are asking.

```
Map<Integer, List<Course>> map = new HashMap<>();

courses.stream().filter(course -> map.keySet().size() < 10)
    .forEach(entry -> {
       // The code below can be simplified
      int teacherId = entry.getTeacher().getTeacherId();
      if(map.get(teacherId) != null)
        map.get(teacherId).add(entry);
      else
        map.put(teacherId, Lists.newArrayList(entry));
    });
```

Comment: Your code relies on the processing order, which is not guaranteed. So it just happens to work with sequential streams using the current implementation…

Comment: Not sure If I understood you correctly, But why would the processing order matter here. I agree it might have to traverse a lot more elements to get the first 10 distinct. But If you first find the 10 distinct and then again go through the list to group, That would be 2n Complexity isn't it

Comment: This has nothing to do with complexity. Your code relies on the assumption that the `filter` predicate will be evaluated for the next element right after `forEach` has added an element, to observe its effect, i.e. the map’s new size. There is no guaranty for this. There’s not even a guaranty that `forEach` will process the elements in the source list’s order. You can fix the terminal operation by using `forEachOrdered`, still, there is no way to guaranty a processing order for the intermediate `filter` operation.

Comment: @Holger I see that this solution will not pick all the Courses for a teacher (as it just checks for the map size). Can you explain a bit on why it won't work for sources generating unordered stream even if `forEachOrdered` is used?

Comment: @user7 `forEachOrdered` only guarantees that the specified consumer is evaluated in the encounter order, if there is one. It doesn’t create any guarantees for the evaluation of the predicate passed to `filter`.